# Error decimal redondea a la hora de actualizar en la base de datos c#

Tags: mysql, c#

El titulo no puede ser mas descriptivo, tengo un error a la hora de actualizar las notas de español para un sistema de notas de un colegio y materias tengo para redondear pero he puesto varias comprobaciones atreves del código, y todas me muestran que hasta antes de insertar por ejemplo valores de 3,5 o 3,2 los redondea a 3,0

**Pantalla del sistema**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Método de la vista**

```
private void calcularNotas()
    {
        Controlador.Controlador controlador = new Controlador.Controlador();
        Modelo.Modelo modelo = new Modelo.Modelo();

        int id;
        decimal nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, notaF;
        string calificacion;

        id = int.Parse(txtidES.Text);
        nota1 = decimal.Parse(txt30ES.Text);
        nota2 = decimal.Parse(txt10ES.Text);
        nota3 = decimal.Parse(txt10ES2.Text);
        nota4 = decimal.Parse(txt10ES3.Text);

        
        notaF = Math.Round(((nota1 * 0.3m) + (nota2 * 0.1m) + (nota3 * 0.1m) + (nota4 * 0.5m)), 1);


        calificacion = controlador.calificaciones(notaF);

        MessageBox.Show("Su calificación es " + Math.Round(notaF, 1).ToString() + " y es " + calificacion);

        modelo.insertarNotas(id, nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, notaF, calificacion);
    }
```

**Modelo**

```
public void insertarNotas(int id, decimal nota1, decimal nota2, decimal nota3, decimal nota4, decimal notaF, string calificacion)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(notaF.ToString());
        string sql = "UPDATE calificacionarea " +
            "SET nota1 = '" + nota1 + "', nota2 = '" + nota2 + "', nota3 = '" + nota3 + "', nota4 = '" + nota4 + "', notaF = '" + notaF + "', Calificacion = '" + calificacion + "' " +
            "WHERE idCalificacionArea = @id;";

        MySqlConnection conexion = Conexion.getConexion();
        

        conexion.Open();
        try
        {
            
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conexion.Close();
        }
        
        
    }
```

**Resultado en la base de datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tipo de datos en la base de datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me olvido decir que en todos los valores me los redondea a 3,0 o a 2,0 o al entero mas cercano no incluí el código del controlador por el hecho de que simplemente me retornaba si la nota era alta, baja o superior

Comment: cuales son los valores que decis que redondea?

Comment: estas seguro de que tus notas llegan a tus scritp con los decimales puestos?

Comment: El problema, como en muchas ocasiones, podría tener que ver con que no estas usando una consulta parametrizada, y quizá no esté detectando correctamente el tipo de datos de las notas que le estás pasando. Prueba usando parametros igual que usas para el id

Comment: @RamiroBarone si puse varios comprobantes como el Console.Writeline en el modelo para certificarme de eso

Comment: @gbianchi los de la nota de español que en este caso son los que actualizo

Comment: @camilohenao creo que el problema es el sql generado, lo genera con ","(coma) y tal vez el espera "."(punto). Podrias probar poner un punto de parada en la linea que dice " string sql=... " y copiar la sentencia generada y correrla directamente en la base. Prueba cambiandole las comas por puntos a ver que tal te va

Comment: En la base de datos me da error si inserto los decimales con , pero si directamente en la consulta pongo valores definidos por mi con . me los redondea en la base de datos

Comment: camilo, probaste a parametrizar la consulta?

Comment: si probe y probe hasta que mire y converti el formato para que me enviara los numeros con . en vez de coma por eso era que me lo redondeaba